# Write PID and Process name to file

Tags: python-3.x, pid

I am trying to have this script do this exactly, and i am just not sure how to write the PID and Process name from the first file to this one.

Write a python script that includes the following:

1. Find a process with the “ps” command and redirect the output to a text document called “myProcess.txt”
2. Using file handling read the file and split the string logically so that you can call on individual parts of the newly created list
3. Create new file called “myData.txt” with the file handle mode set to write
4. Write to the new file with these two items  PID and Process Name
5. Finally the script must delete the first file (myProcess.txt)

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/python3

   import os 

   os.system("ps > myProcess.txt") 
   process = open("myProcess.txt","r")

   data = process.read()
   cleanData = data.split("\n")


   filename = open("myData.txt","w")
   for row in cleanData:
           filename.write(row[1])
   ```

This is what the myProcess.txt file looks like

```
PID TTY          TIME CMD
4759 pts/1    00:00:00 sudo
4760 pts/1    00:00:00 su
4761 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
7022 pts/1    00:00:00 python3
7023 pts/1    00:00:00 sh
7024 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
```

Comment: Is this related to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63908168/how-can-you-find-a-process-with-the-ps-command-direct-it-to-a-txt-file)?

Comment: Note that this can be trivially solved by having ``ps`` write out only the PID and CMD. See the ``ps`` man page how to configure its output.